# В консоли на странице с каптчей вылетает ошибка

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, recaptcha

прошу помочь.
У меня на сайте есть две страницы с каптчей 2.0 от гугл, на них в консоли вылетает ошибка 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of null at sso.js:1` 
Вот ссылки на страницы:

[Страница с регистрацией](https://sport.ardupy3000.ru/register)

[Баг репорт](https://sport.ardupy3000.ru/bug/report)

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ничего не вылетает, ошибок нет, капча работает

Comment: Попробуйте кеш почистить

Comment: Спасибо, кеш почистил, но всё равно вылетает, и я Вас с сайта, как пользователя удалю, а то у меня сайт для школьников с соревнованиями

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простите, затупил

Это ошибка chrome расширения office online. Но выходит оно только на страницах с каптчей